# Rotate a string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, rotation, jquery-animate

I have a lot of the basics down, but I'm going through w3resource sample problems (https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-basic-exercises.php - question 5) and I'm really confused. The below code is w3's solution on how to rotate a string. I have 6 questions. If you can help me understand any 1, or all, I'd greatly appreciate it because this novice is struggling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<body onload="animate_string('target')" 

  <pre id="target">Look at me move! </pre>  

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function animate_string(id)
```

1. Why do we write this function (animate_string) with the parameter 'id' when above we already specified the 'id' name and its parameter?

```
{
    var element = document.getElementById(id); 
    var textNode = element.childNodes[0];
```

2. why do we need childNodes?

```
        var text = textNode.data;
```

3. Why data?

```
    setInterval(function () 
{
 text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
```

4. Why does it loop?

```
      textNode.data = text;
```

5. We already said that text = textNode.data. Why again here?

```
    }, 100);
```

6. Why is the closing parenthesis outside of the curly braces?
        }

```
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `w3resource.com` has absolutely nothing to do with the actual W3C other than the "w" and the "3".

Answer (score 0):

1. For the ability to pass dynamic values to the function
2. To get a collection of text nodes that are children of the parent node.
3. `data` is a property of a text node that has a value equivalent to `.textContent`
4. To "Rotate" the string
5. To set `data` property of the text node to the last index of `data` with a string concatenated
6. To close `setInterval()` function call

Comment: Thank you so much. But with regard to #1, I see that the parameter in `function animate_string(id)` corresponds dynamically with `var element = document.getElementById(id);`  But my main question is - does it correspond with the HTML `id="target"` ?? When I test it and give the parameters different (but matching) names in the JS, it still works. Is it just coincidence that the parameters in the JS match the HTML (id)??

Comment: Yes. The function expects a string `id` to be passed which is then used at `document.getElementById(id)`. `'target'` is passed as an argument to the function at `animate_string('target')`. An error should occur if `id` is not passed to the function call `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getElementById' on 'Document': 1 argument required, but only 0 presen` or the passed argument does not match an element having `id` within the `document`, because `document.getElementById('noElementInDocumentHasThisId')` returns `null`

Comment: Resulting in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null` at next line `var textNode = element.childNodes[0];` `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null`

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me, that clears it up, I think. I think I was confused because they used the name 'id' in the JS functions. But really, if I understand this right, we could have used anything, like - document.getElementById(zebra) and function animate_string(zebra) and left the HTML alone, right? –

Comment: Yes, though the argument is expected to be a string in each case, unless `zebra` references a string `var zebra = "target"`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function animate_string() {
    const element = document.getElementById("ulta");
    const output1 = document.querySelector('#result1')
    console.log(element)
    let text = element.value;
    console.log(typeof (text))

    setInterval(function () {
        text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);  //A string is just a one-dimensional array — a vector — with elements of the type character.
        // output1.textContent = text;
        output1.innerHTML = text; //also work
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="ulta" />
    <button onclick="animate_string()">make it reverse</button>
    <p id="result1"></p>
    <script src="index.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```